# frame using a Background-image

Tags: html, css, image, frame

I put a frame in my images.

I created a CSS for the background-image is the image of the frame, but he must have an x padding for the frame is seen.

```
img.frame
{
    background-image:url('http://bit.ly/k8g8zz');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100%;
    padding:23px 14px 60px;
}
```

I can not use a div inside of another because I need this image is a link with a title, and  the W3C can not be div tags within a.

If possible, change the jsFiddle and send me the link

See the [complete code here](http://jsfiddle.net/Db2m6/).

As you can see in jsFiddle, the frame is the wrong size .. she needs to grow along with the image and have a padding.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost have it! Just set both dimensions of `background-size`;

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vLBXH/

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a width and height for a background-image in CSS, AFAIK. If you use a fixed-width image (PNG) you also should have images of the matching size. Another approach might be to style the frame with CSS only or have an framing-tag around the linked image, which you then may style, like:

```
<div class="img_frame">
    <a href="#nohref"><imgr src="#noimg" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I can not put in a div, as I have a text link as well (see the link jsFiddle) <p> has an element that should be a link, you put inside the div, everyone will frame;